# Which pins support i2c protocols?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

I have a  ESP32-WROOM-32D , it support I2c protocol but when i refer the i2c

pins(SDA,SCL) in datasheet ,i couldn't find .

datasheet is given below.

which pins that support i2c protocols?

[datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32d_esp32-wroom-32u_datasheet_en.pdf)

thanks

Comment: I see you asked several questions, but you haven't 'accept'ed any. Please consider to accept previous answers if they were helpful. It's a nice way to thank the people who spend their time helping you.

Answer (score 2):

Check chapter 4:

> **4. Peripherals and Sensors**
>   Please refer to Section Peripherals and Sensors in [ESP32 Datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf).

Follow that link and read chapter `4.2 Peripheral Pin Configurations` in that document.

It says you can assign it to `Any GPIO Pins`

Comment: It's very help full.. Thanks a lot..